# VsCode appears to keep running wxPython app when it should have stopped

Tags: visual-studio-code, wxpython

In my VsCode wxPython application under Windows, I bind the close event to my function as follows:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title = title, pos = (150, 0))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
        # Other stuff ...

    def OnClose(self, event):
        print("closing")
        self.Destroy()

app = wx.App()
top = MyFrame("My App")
top.Show()
app.MainLoop()
print("done")
```

Now I can *see* it's being called when I close the top level window (a `wxFrame`) as the `closing` and `done` messages appear. The window itself also disappears.

However VsCode thinks the application is still running since it has the debug controls still available:

[image]

and the console that ran it (Python debug console) does not come back with a prompt. It's not until I click on the stop button does the command prompt reappear in that console.

Interestingly, if I run the application *outside* of VsCode, it exits correctly, returning to the command prompt.

Comment: what happens if you add `event.Skip()` to your `OnClose` handler? I think `self.Destroy` is unnecessary b/c `wx.Frame`s are automatically destroyed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `wx.Exit()` in case you have something still open/running without realising it.

> wx.Exit()
>   Exits application after calling wx.App.OnExit .
>
> Should only be used in an emergency: normally the top-level frame should be deleted (after deleting all other frames) to terminate the application. See wx.CloseEvent and wx.App.

Comment: Rolf, that *does* work by placing it in the main line after return from `app.MainLoop()` but I'm not sure why it's needed (nor of its potential flaws). Outside of VsCode, it exits perfectly without that, so I'm not sure if VsCode *itself* injects some Python code which prevents shutdown. Have updated the question with that info but, in any case, here's a vote for helping out.